# How to call a method to load class variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, static-methods, static-variables

The data is loaded once because it takes a while to load, doesn't change, and is shared. This is a static class: I am not using any instances.

```
class Foo
  @@ data = self.load_data

  def self.load_data
    .
    . 
    .
  end

  def self.calculate
    .
    .
  end
end
```

This throws an error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'load_data' for Foo:Class` because load_data appears after the assignment.

I don't think initialize will work because I am not using `f = Foo.new`. I am using it as `Foo.calculate`.

Is it necessary to declare load_data before calling it? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Foo.load_data doesn't exist yet at the point you call it.

A better pattern might be to have an accessor for @@data which auto-memoizes.

```
class Foo
  def self.data
    @@data ||= load_data
  end
  def data; self.class.data; end # if you need it in instances too

  def self.load_data
    ...
  end

  def self.calculate
    data.each {} # or whatever would have used @@data
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Load data by class level function call.

```
class Foo
  def self.load_data
    .
    . 
    .
    @data = value
  end

  def self.calculate
   #use @data in this function.
   .
   .
  end
end

#first load data
Foo.load_data

#then process data
Foo.calculate
```

Comment: `Foo.calculate` is run through a cron job, so there is no good time to call `load_data`. In this case it's better to auto-load somehow...

Comment: then call load_data from calculate method.